# Not able to fetch the variable name in the regular expression extractor

Tags: apache, jmeter, load

I am not able to fetch the variable name from regular expression. The variable name is actually used as RandomstringFunction which i am storing in ${BusinessUnitName} but some how regular exprssion is not fetching this value, can you help me in knowing how to solve this.

Check this image for the regular expression:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more details, please? Json example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any [JMeter Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the "Regular Expression" input of the Regular Expression Extractor, given the variable has its anticipated value and there is a match in the response body - it will return a result.

Just check your `BusinessUnitName` variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) and if:

- the variable is defined and has the value
- if the value is in the response

your regular expression will work normally.

In general if you're trying to look for a random string in the response body using regular expressions it will fail so it's kind of expected